# Running Docker on WSL not executing "RUN" instruction, nor building properly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Docker Desktop installed, and have followed the below guide to setting everything up to work with WSL.

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly

At first when trying to build a image i got the following error.
Command: "docker build -t hello ."

[image]

Which i fixed by putting this in my console:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
```

I could now successfully build / run my docker image:

[image]

I get "test" outputted to my console, but the problem is that no txt file is being created. It should be since I'm getting a output and "cat" is reading from the file, but it does not appear in the folder in which I run the image? I cannot find it anywhere else either. Any advice?

Comment: That Dockerfile creates the `helloWorld.txt` inside the container, not on your local machine (or not directly visible in the host machine). Are you looking inside the container for that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile creates the `helloWorld.txt` file inside the container itself and it won't be visible on your local filesystem. If you've built the image and tagged as `hello`, you can get a shell into the system with:

```sh
docker run -it hello:latest /bin/bash
```

This will give you a bash shell into the machine where you should be able to view the output:

```sh
$ docker run -it hello:latest /bin/bash
root@88a2b4c7d88e:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  helloWorld.txt  home  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation really helped.

Out of curiosity, if I wanted to create a file locally in that folder when running the image, how would I go about it? Or is it even possible in the first place?

Comment: You're welcome! That's definitely possible. You can mount a directory from your host machine to the container when you run it so they'll share one or more directories. For example, adding `-v $PWD:/home` mounts the current directory to `/home` inside the container (if you're on a macOS/linux system):  `docker run -it -v $PWD:/home hello:latest /bin/bash`. If you run `ls /home` you should see and modify the same files from where you ran the docker command. More details about Docker volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I feel kinda dumb for not realizing that stuff happens INSIDE a container and doesn't affect your system directly in that sense. I just started on learning docker today and it should have been obvious, but I thought too much about it and made myself think something was wrong because I didn't see a file appear. Haha. 

Thanks a lot again!

Oh and I'm running a WSL shell on windows, since I don't want to have Linux as my main operating system and I read that docker has a lot of issues when running it purely from windows.

Comment: Of course, that's totally understandable. Containers are complicated and it's a foreign concept to most people when you're learning about them for the first time (myself included).